# estimate quantity function q(p) from log estimates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I'm trying to create a demand curve to measure the demand of an asset as a function of its price.  In research I've found others who have determined using empirical data that:

$ ln(q) = -0.7ln(p) $ where q is the qty demanded and p is the price of the asset.

The above implies that the %change in $q = -.7*$%change in p given the log transform.

However if I raise e^() to both sides of the equation I cannot seem to find the quantity as a function of price formula:

$q = p^{-.7}$

The above clearly doesn't give the quantity function.  I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing? I suspect Q is some type of exponential function of price p, but how do I find that from the above natural log equation?

Answer (score 1):

$q = p^{-0.7}$ looks like a quantity function.

[image: graph]

You don't give any units, so this is a terrible graph...

Comment: how would you set the y-intercept since this asymptotes to infinity as $p \implies 0$? Here the y-intercept fo course is initial quantity assuming price = 0

Comment: @mathcompguy : If the price is zero, what theory would bound quantity demanded?

Comment: @mathcompguy : (...  some other theory that doesn't assume the marginal rate of change in the two quantities is related by the constant $-0.7$ everywhere, but that requires more facts than the one given model equation.)

Comment: I just don't see how you can use that function, if I do a linear approximation it makes more sense albeit there's error: $Q_{0}*(1-dp/p) = Q_{1}.$.  What I'm looking for is the exact equation of Q(p) given the -0.7 coefficient of the per cent change

Comment: @mathcompguy : You have it.  You are wishing to extend it beyond its domain of validity.  This is not something the equation can do for you; you need additional theory or data to find how to model at prices around zero.

Comment: Actually what I ended up doing was using the exponential thus I set Q(p) = $Q_{0}e^{-.7p}$, note however p IS NOT the price but the per cent change in price from some start point $(P_0,Q_0)$.  Although this works, I am looking for a more robust solution that involves the price p instead of a per cent change in p as the variable